# Updating IValueConverter through code

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to update an IValueConverter through the code behind.

My situation is that I've got two ComboBoxes. Once the first one is updated, I change the ItemsSource property of the second to be one of a variety of enums. I've grabbed an EnumToFriendlyNameConverter from CodeProject, but I'm not sure how to set it.

If I set the converter in the ItemsSource (see below) then it gets ignored when I next set the items source.

`ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource enumItemsConverter}}"`

I found that it is possible by using an ItemTemplate but then I have to manually place in a label, which then has a different style to my other combobox. Getting the styles right just seems like a lot of work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the ItemsSource you just have to apply the converter again or modify the ItemsSource instead of replacing it.

e.g. create a new binding:

```
private void ChangeItemsSouce(IEnumerable newItems)
{
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.Source = newItems;
    binding.Converter = new EnumToFriendlyNameConverter();
    comboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
}
```

Or modify the existing binding:

```
private void ChangeItemsSouce(IEnumerable newItems)
{
    var binding = comboBox.GetBindingExpression(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty);
    binding.ParentBinding.Source = newItems;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I have the code to test it anymore, but it sounds quite plausible, so I'll assume you're correct. Thanks :)