# Apply ValueConverter by code to LongListSelector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, model-binding

I have PivotPage with some PivotItems each with an own `LongListSelector`:

```
<phone:PivotItem x:Name="pivotitem1" Header="Headline 1">
... same like in pivotitem2 ...
</phone:PivotItem>

<phone:PivotItem x:Name="pivotitem2" Header="Headline 2">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lst2" Margin="12,0,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myLocationsListTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        </phone:LongListSelector>
    </Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>

<phone:PivotItem x:Name="pivotitem3" Header="Headline 3">
... same like in pivotitem2 ...
</phone:PivotItem>
```

All LongListSelector are using same DataTemplate, so I declared it globally as StaticRessource.

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="myLocationsListTemplate">
    <Button Click="btn_ShowLocationDetails_Click" Tag="{Binding ID}" Style="{StaticResource mBlankButton}" Margin="1,0,-1,0">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,15" >
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,22" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="138" Height="25" Source="/mAppData/stars-3.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DistanceInMeterFormatted, FallbackValue=fallback, TargetNullValue=nullvalue, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,-3,20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LastUploadAgo}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding PreviewImg1}"/>
                <Image Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding PreviewImg2}"/>
                <Image Grid.Column="2" Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding PreviewImg3}"/>
                <Image Grid.Column="3" Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding PreviewImg4}"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

In in `OnNavigateTo` I give to a corresponding model. I apply the model by code :

```
pivotitem1.DataContext = ...
pivotitem2.DataContext = App.ViewSurroundingsData;
pivotitem3.DataContext = ...
```

In `App.ViewSourroundingsData` is my ObservableCollection globally stored.

The collection contains a list of object with a lot of properties. One specific property is an integer: `imgcnt` - it holds the amount of images.

Now I want to make all list entries invisible when `imgcnt` is 0.

I researched, that I could use a ValuesConverter. But I don´t know how to code this with a depedency to my integer value in the class property. I can´t extend the solution found on [Updating IValueConverter through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053572/updating-ivalueconverter-through-code).

I don´t know how to make a whole list entry invisible, when the property `imgcnt` is 0.
And I don´t know how to apply the converter by code (in OnNavigateTo) only to my ItemTemplate for `pivotitem2`.

Can anyone help?

UPDATE:
I did following with no success (all entries are not shown):

```
pivotitem1.DataContext = App.ViewSurroundingsData;
Binding mBinding = new Binding();
mBinding.Source = App.ViewSurroundingsData;
mBinding.Converter = new IntegerToVisibilityConverter();
lst2.SetBinding(LongListSelector.ItemsSourceProperty, mBinding);
```

And

```
public sealed class IntegerToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        var item = (ViewModels.ViewModel_Surroundings)value;
        if (item.imgcnt == 0) 
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else 
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: Is it mandatory that you apply converter via code? It will be easier to do it in xaml. And do you want to hide the whole LLS or the specific item(s)?

Comment: No it must not be by code. But it must be seperate for each of the three LongListSelectors. And no, i only want to make These items invisible, that have `imgcnt` = 0.

Comment: So every item has this property `imgcnt`, and when it's 0 then that item should be invisible? From your code I see that you try to use converter to ImageSource of LLS, you destroy the Binding from xaml, also putting there Visibility is no good.

Comment: Yes, but how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just bind the `imgcnt` to the `Visibility` of the Button like this?

```
    <Button Click="btn_ShowLocationDetails_Click" Tag="{Binding ID}" Style="{StaticResource mBlankButton}" Margin="1,0,-1,0" 
Visibility="{Binding imgcnt, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

And then in your converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
    {
        return (int)value == 0 ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Or am I missing something here? ;-)

Comment: (+1) You were one minute faster. Just few remarks: OP should remove his Binding from OnNavigatedTo, `imgcnt` must be a public property and sometimes he may need to `RaiseProperty("imgcnt");` - but those things depend on OP's code.

Comment: Yes, he just needs to implement INPC for that property (better yet, for the whole class).

Comment: No this doesn´t work anyway. XAML designer says: "The ressource IntegerToVisibilityConverter could not be resolved.". Can this be because of having the DataTempleta in the ressource section?

Comment: Ok now I got it: Defined the convert in my global Namespace and added a ressource to my app.xaml. So your Suggestion works as excpected. BUT: Now all my entries are invisible if imgcnt = 0. I "re-use" the DataTemplate in more than one PivotItem. In some of them I WANT TO be them VISIBLE. That´s the reason why I wanted to add the converter by code. Any further ideas?

Comment: Overwrite the property imgcnt in 'some' of your classes, so that it's not 0?

Comment: Nope - can´t manipulate this because it´s an important info to show. Now I defined simple 2 light different DataTemplates - one with and one without the converter on the button. Now everthings is fine. THX !

Comment: If you have any idea, how to bind the converter to the button in c#, please let me know. It would be perfect, not to have two different templates only because of the converter...